# How this navigation bar is created on the top of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

Can any one give me the CSS and html code for it?

`https://www.mi.com/en/`

this is the link of the website which I am trying to implement the navigation bar but I am not understanding how it's navigation bar created on the slider.

---

```html
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
   
            <br />
         <nav class="navbar ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
<img id="logo" src="image/logo.jpg" />
        </div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
        <div class="searchform group">
            
        <label for="search-box">
        <span class="fa fa-2x fa-search"></span>
        </label>
  
        <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search"/>

        </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to show your work. It is difficult to read bulk of codes. State clearly what you want and what does not match your expectation instead of just "how to do it".

Comment: Look here, there are several examples of what you want, and you get the code. https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for slider wrapper
position: absolute;

then you can create you navigation bar above or below that wrapper by having z index greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of w3schools examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.mySlides {display: none}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">HOME</a>
    <a href="#band" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">BAND</a>
    <a href="#tour" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">TOUR</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">CONTACT</a>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
      <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="More">MORE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>     
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Merchandise</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Extras</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Media</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-red w3-hide-small w3-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Navbar on small screens (remove the onclick attribute if you want the navbar to always show on top of the content when clicking on the links) -->
<div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-black w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium w3-top" style="margin-top:46px">
  <a href="#band" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">BAND</a>
  <a href="#tour" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">TOUR</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large" onclick="myFunction()">MERCH</a>
</div>

<!-- Page content -->
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:2000px;margin-top:46px">

  <!-- Automatic Slideshow Images -->
  <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/la.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
      <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
      <p><b>We had the best time playing at Venice Beach!</b></p>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
      <h3>New York</h3>
      <p><b>The atmosphere in New York is lorem ipsum.</b></p>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
      <h3>Chicago</h3>
      <p><b>Thank you, Chicago - A night we won't forget.</b></p>    
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- End Page Content -->
</div>
<script>
// Automatic Slideshow - change image every 4 seconds
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 4000);    
}

// Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
        x.className += " w3-show";
    } else { 
        x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
    }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
var modal = document.getElementById('ticketModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am asking about navigation bar on the slider, not above sorry... how this will happen??

Comment: as you can see in the templates, they place the titles of the images the way you would place links if links is what you want. im not writing the code for you; what i gave you has the answer, i have made it many times.